# Preferences Error "Could not load Sharing preference pane" El Capitan

Tags: xamarin, osx-elcapitan

Need to use Mac as Xamarin Mac Agent and configure remote login.

Anyone come across this error?

Comment: This is really a general OS X question, not anything specifically related to programming.  See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52001/the-system-preference-panes-will-not-load

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, permissions are be changed so you are not able to see some panels. To fix it, you should restart your computer in SafeMode

Safe Mode boot deletes system caches that may help after an OS X upgrade.
Top left corner of your screen click the  Apple   > Shut Down.
After your Mac shuts down, wait 10 seconds, then press the power button.
Immediately after you hear the startup tone, hold down the Shift key. You should press the Shift key as soon as possible after you hear the startup tone, but not before.
Release the Shift key when you see the gray Apple logo and progress indicator.
Once you are in Safe Mode, enter the Sharing panel (without changing anything) and then go back to the Apple  menu. From the drop down menu click:  Restart.

This should fix the problem. If not, you should try to restore all files permission by using "Repair disk permission" utility. To do this,
open Disk Utility, which is in the Utilities folder of your Applications folder.
Select the startup disk from the list of volumes.
Click the First Aid tab.
To check permissions, click Verify Disk Permissions. To repair permissions, click Repair Disk Permissions.
Disk Utility checks a file's permissions only if the file has a corresponding receipt in /var/db/receipts. The receipt tells Disk Utility what the permissions should be. Not all installers include a receipt with the files they install.

I hope it helps.